# Regex pattern that matches only if not included in another pattern

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I am trying to understand how to make a regular expression that only matches a pattern if this pattern is not included in another one.

In the following example, I want to match dashes only if they are not into a [code][/code] tag.

```
---------

[code]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Some text

-----------------

Some other text

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test

[/code]
```

I have searched for explanations about lookahead and lookbehind but cannot understand if and how it could be suitable for what I need.

I wanted to use a combination of negative lookbehind and negative lookahead but it seems that it is not possible to use + or * in negative lookbehind pattern.

So, for example, this won't work (because of the + in the negative look behind)

```
/(?<!\[code\].+?)(-{5,100})(?!.+?\[\/code\])/m
```

How can I achieve that in another way ?

Comment: You are right, *it is not possible to use `+` or `*` in ... lookbehind pattern*. Are you extracting, replacing, removing, or maybe splitting?

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea. It is about replacing the dashes by <hr> tags as part of a forum migration (from BBCode syntax to Markdown) but only if they are not in a code tag.

Comment: Ok, and can `[code]` tags be nested? Note that `/\[code\].*?\[\/code\]/m` will match `[code] abc [code] def [/code]`, and `/\[code\](?:(?!\[\/?code\]).)*\[\/code\]/m` will only match `[code] def [/code]`, but neither will match `[code] abc [code] def [/code] ghi [/code]` in full.

Comment: No, they cannot.

I could start by matching and removing all code portion from the message (storing them in an array) and replacing them by a marker in the message, then running my replacements and finally putting the code portions back from the temporary array ;)

Comment: |Well, then use `s.gsub(/(\[code\].*?\[\/code\])|-{5,100}/m) { $1 || "<hr/>" }` or `s.gsub(/(\[code\](?:(?!\[\/?code\]).)*\[\/code\])|-{5,100}/m) { $1 || "<hr/>" }`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility if the tags are not nested is to match from the opening till the closing tag to match what you don't want. Then use an alternation to capture in a group what you do want, in this case 5 - 100 times a hyphen.

```
\[code\](?:(?!\[\/?code\]).)*\[\/code]|(-{5,100})/m
```

**Explanation**

- `\[code\]` Match `[code]`
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!\[\/?code\]).` Assert if what is on the right is not `[code]` with an optional `/` after the opening `[` Then match any character.
- `)*` Repeat non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\[\/code]` Match `[/code]`
- `|` Or
- `(-{5,100})` Capture in group 1 matching 5 - 100 times a hyphen

[Regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/9x7OXeLdXlYSO7)

Comment: You do not need `[\s\S]` workaround if `m` flag is used (and OP uses it), `.` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe a regular expression is the right tool for the job here.

```
str = <<END
---------
[code]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Some text
----------------------------------
Some other text
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
test
[/code]
------------
---
[code]
Some text
-------------------------------------------
[/code]
------------
END
```

```
within = false
str.split("\n").select do |line|
  case line
  when "[code]"
    within = true
    false
  when "[/code]"
    within = false
    false
  else
    within == false
  end
end
  #=> ["---------", "------------", "---", "------------"]
```

I would have used the to-some-beloved [flip-flip operator](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/) had it not been deprecated.

```
 str.split("\n").reject do |line|
   true if line == "[code]"..line == "[/code]"
 end
   #=> ["---------", "------------", "---", "------------"]
```

[Hold the phone!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:hold_the_phone#targetText=Talk%3Ahold%20the%20phone&targetText=I%20believe%20this%20expression%20originated,editors%20from%20public%20phone%20boxes.) It looks like Matz has [un-deprecated it](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/cjk8e1/undeprecate_flipflop/?ref=readnext)! (Scroll to end.)